# What are some good sources to learn fraud/anomaly detection in normal/time-series data?

Tags: data-mining, time-series, anomaly-detection

I would like to know more on fraud/anomaly detection. I am looking for good source or survey article/book etc out there which will give me some preliminary idea of the area.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have answered a **very similar question** here: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/5200/2452. My _related answer_ on _Cross Validated_ might also be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142725/31372.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is done as outliers analysis (fraud is an outlier vs normal usage). For this aspect, you can find more info in the [data mining: concepts and techniques](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123814791) book, even if general purpose book.

I am convinced that learning this kind of basis is needed to understanding the domain specific methods.

Comment: You are welcome. Hoping this helps...

Answer (score 4):

[Chandola et al's survey](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~banerjee/papers/09/anomaly.pdf) is probably the best and most-widely cited survey in the anomaly detection field.